# Python OOP importing child class from parent class

Tags: python, oop

Every business rule I create, it gets placed in a folder called "rule_definitions."

I have a class `Rule`. It acts as a template for all these created rules that they can inherit necessary generic functions from.

An example of the folder contents:

```
rule_definitions/
    discard.py
    saveValue.py
    storeValue.py
    writeToOutput.py
```

But if you want to create an instance of a rule, it's very clean to just do:

`rule = Rule('discard')` and have the `Rule` class do the importing itself, rather than finding the appropriate rule module every time you need to load a rule.

For example, the content of `rule_definitions.py` might be:

```
from Rule import Rule

class _discard(Rule):
    ...
```

And within `Rule`, we might have:

```
import importlib

class Rule():
    """A template class that all rules inherit from and are instantiated from."""

    def __init__(self, rule):
        # load the rule by name from rule definitions
        try:
            self.Rule = importlib.import_module('defs._'+ rule)
        except ImportError:
            print 'Failed to find rule definiton while attempting to load


    #other generic functions to inherit below
```

Is this the cleanest way? I'm not sure if this would be standard practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Let me do it one by one:

- What you propose doesn't really require `_discard` to inherit from `Rule`. You're using both inheritance and composition, which looks confusing.
- The rule you return still has the type `Rule`, not `_discard`. Maybe that's what you want, maybe not...
- `Rule('discard')` cannot be statically checked and won't get autocompletion you expect (if you're using IDE).

Here are some ideas for improvements:

- Pure composition: Keep the current initialisation, but don't inherit from `Rule`. Either use another class for the generic functionality, or pass the parent into `_discard` constructor. (the second one will produce reference loops though)

With another class for generic functionality it can look like this:

```
class RuleTrait(object):
    def some_common_stuff(self):
        ...

class _discard(RuleTrait):
    def do_work(self):
        some_common_stuff()

class Rule(object):
    def __init__(self, typ):
        self.impl = _get_impl_by_name(typ)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.impl, name)

Rule("discard").do_work()  # this will be forwarded to _discard.do_work
```

- Actual inheritance: Don't use the generic constructor, but the direct classes instead. `Rule('discard')` is not worse than `rules.Discard()`, and it will give you better type checks. And you can get rid of the import magic.
- If you need more import magic in some cases, make it a factory instead. `Rule(...)` can only create a `Rule` object. But you can write a `make_rule('discard')` instead with whatever implementation you need.

Comment: Yes, I want every rule to be of type `Rule` in this scenario for clarity, not `_discard`. But a question regarding your first solution on using another class for generic functionality, how would this work? Say I have the `RuleTemplate` class that `_discard` and all other created rules inherit from. If I create a rule, e.g.: `r = Rule('discard')` - I can't execute the generic functions like `Rule.execute(args)` or `Rule.getName()`.

Comment: @X33 I added a sample. You can forward all the unknown attributes to the actual implementation. Your class with generic rule traits doesn't have to be public though.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I really appreciate the clarification. This is probably the best approach for my given situation. If you have time, I have one final question: Regarding the factory approach, is this solution not very similar to a factory?

Comment: @X33 Similar, but with a factory, you can take a name as a string and then return a specific class rather than the generic `Rule`. If you don't need that, you don't need the factory. But sometimes it could be useful to do an `isinstance(something, rules.Discard)` for example. Specifically if you ever wanted the rules to have a hierarchy as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing looks similar to dynamically loading database migrations.
Django and similar database related projects may have code you could look at.

I wrote some code that does automatic loading and importing.
Look at the `load_migrations` function I wrote here [https://github.com/someones/exodus/blob/master/exodus/**init**.py](https://github.com/someones/exodus/blob/master/exodus/__init__.py)

1. The core Exodus class loads migrations from a specified directory.
2. Each file will have a class that extends the BaseMigration object.
3. The BaseMigration's metaclass will register itself with a central list of migrations at parse time.